# JQuery tooltip jumps rows in gridview when hovering over a tooltip cell - how to prevent?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, gridview

In the following asp.net sample webform app (markup and code behind follows below along with sample data) I apply a JQuery tooltip, using a webmethod, to one cell in a gridview with 5 columns -- which the requirement is "No Paging" on the gridview they want scrolling gridview.  The datasource in my sample contains 26 rows from A to Z.  I set the height of the div which contains the gridview to height 300px so that I get a scrollbar to illustrate my problem.  The tooltip works ok except 1) when hovering over the cell for the tooltip (column 1 in my sample) the row expands and the cells for that row get pushed to the right of the column 1 cell -- like a phantom cell was added after cell(1).   And ... 2) if you scroll towards the bottom of the gridview -- towards the zzz row (where aaa thru fff rows not visible) when you hover over a tooltip cell in column 1 the gridview rows jump back to like the j row.

How can I prevent this from happening -- the jumping of rows?  Is it possible to prevent the cells from being pushed to the right when hovering over the tooltip cell?  prevent the phantom cell from appearing?  How to remedy this/these problems?  Is this JQuery issue or CSS issue?

**--Markup here**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm3" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
      <title>WebForm3</title>

      <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm3.aspx/GetMyStuff",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data: {},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {                        
              $('[id*=GridViewA] tr').each(function (n) {
                $(this).find("td:eq(1)").each(function () {                                
                  var titel = typeof (data.d[n - 1]) === 'undefined' ? "" : data.d[n - 1].firstN + "<br />" + data.d[n - 1].lastN;        
                  $(this).tooltip({ title: $(this).addClass("colr-tooltip"), title: titel, html: true, placement: "bottom" });
                });
              });
            },
            error: function () { alert("error"); }
          });
        });

      </script>

      <style type="text/css">
        .colr-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner
        {
          width: 200px;
          max-width: 600px !important;
          background-color: gainsboro;
          color: blue;
          text-align: left;
          opacity: 1;
          filter: alpha(opacity=100);  
          -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px black;
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px black;
          box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px black;   
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="height:300px; width:310px; overflow:auto;">                
          <asp:GridView ID="GridViewA" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true" AllowPaging="false" >
            <Columns>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="itm0" HeaderText="itm0A" />                
              <asp:BoundField DataField="itm1" HeaderText="itm1B" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="itm2" HeaderText="itm2C" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="itm3" HeaderText="itm3D" />  
              <asp:BoundField DataField="itm4" HeaderText="itm4E" />  
            </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>
        </div>
      </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**--code behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                List<stuffA> lstA = new List<stuffA>()
               {
                    new stuffA {itm0="a1", itm1="aaa", itm2="apple", itm3="anna smith", itm4 = "aaa"},
                    new stuffA{itm0="b1", itm1 = "bbb", itm2="banana", itm3="betty white", itm4 = "bbb"},
                    new stuffA{itm0="c1", itm1 = "ccc", itm2="cow", itm3="charlie sheen", itm4 = "ccc"},
                    new stuffA{itm0="d1", itm1 = "ddd", itm2="donut", itm3="danielle monet", itm4 = "ddd"},
                    new stuffA{itm0="e1", itm1 = "eee", itm2="egret", itm3="emelio esteban", itm4 = "eee"},
                    new stuffA {itm0="f1", itm1="fff", itm2="fapple", itm3="fanna smith", itm4 = "fff"},
                    new stuffA{itm0="g1", itm1 = "ggg", itm2="gbanana", itm3="gbetty white", itm4 = "ggg"},
                    new stuffA{itm0="h1", itm1 = "hhh", itm2="hcow", itm3="hcharlie sheen", itm4 = "hhh"},
                    new stuffA{itm0="i1", itm1 = "iii", itm2="idonut", itm3="idanielle monet", itm4 = "iii"},
                    new stuffA{itm0="j1", itm1 = "jjj", itm2="jegret", itm3="jemelio esteban", itm4 = "jjj"},
                    new stuffA {itm0="k1", itm1="kkk", itm2="kapple", itm3="kanna smith", itm4 = "kkk"},
                    new stuffA{itm0="l1", itm1 = "lll", itm2="lbanana", itm3="lbetty white", itm4 = "lll"},
                    new stuffA{itm0="m1", itm1 = "mmm", itm2="mcow", itm3="mcharlie sheen", itm4 = "mmm"},
                    new stuffA{itm0="n1", itm1 = "nnn", itm2="ndonut", itm3="ndanielle monet", itm4 = "nnn"},
                    new stuffA{itm0="o1", itm1 = "ooo", itm2="oegret", itm3="oemelio esteban", itm4 = "ooo"},
                    new stuffA {itm0="p1", itm1="ppp", itm2="papple", itm3="panna smith", itm4 = "ppp"},
                    new stuffA{itm0="q1", itm1 = "qqq", itm2="qbanana", itm3="qbetty white", itm4 = "qqq"},
                    new stuffA{itm0="r1", itm1 = "rrr", itm2="rcow", itm3="rcharlie sheen", itm4 = "rrr"},
                    new stuffA{itm0="s1", itm1 = "sss", itm2="sdonut", itm3="sdanielle monet", itm4 = "sss"},
                    new stuffA{itm0="t1", itm1 = "ttt", itm2="tegret", itm3="temelio esteban", itm4 = "ttt"},
                    new stuffA{itm0="u1", itm1 = "uuu", itm2="uegret", itm3="uemelio esteban", itm4 = "uuu"},
                    new stuffA {itm0="v1", itm1="vvv", itm2="vapple", itm3="vanna smith", itm4 = "vvv"},
                    new stuffA{itm0="w1", itm1 = "www", itm2="wbanana", itm3="wbetty white", itm4 = "www"},
                    new stuffA{itm0="x1", itm1 = "xxx", itm2="xcow", itm3="xcharlie sheen", itm4 = "xxx"},
                    new stuffA{itm0="y1", itm1 = "yyy", itm2="ydonut", itm3="ydanielle monet", itm4 = "yyy"},
                    new stuffA{itm0="z1", itm1 = "zzz", itm2="zegret", itm3="zemelio esteban", itm4 = "zzz"}
               };

                GridViewA.DataSource = lstA;
                GridViewA.DataBind();
            }
        }

        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static stuffB[] GetMyStuff() 
        {
            List<stuffB> Detail = new List<stuffB> {                
                new stuffB{firstN="alfred", lastN="Newman"},
                new stuffB{firstN="betty", lastN="white"},
                new stuffB{firstN="connie", lastN="stevens"},
                new stuffB{firstN="davy", lastN="jones"},
                new stuffB{firstN="efron", lastN="smith"},
                new stuffB{firstN="fff", lastN="Newman"},
                new stuffB{firstN="ggg", lastN="white"},
                new stuffB{firstN="hhh", lastN="stevens"},
                new stuffB{firstN="iii", lastN="jones"},
                new stuffB{firstN="jjj", lastN="smith"},
                new stuffB{firstN="kkk", lastN="Newman"},
                new stuffB{firstN="lll", lastN="white"},
                new stuffB{firstN="mmm", lastN="stevens"},
                new stuffB{firstN="nnn", lastN="jones"},
                new stuffB{firstN="ooo", lastN="smith"},
                new stuffB{firstN="ppp", lastN="Newman"},
                new stuffB{firstN="qqq", lastN="white"},
                new stuffB{firstN="rrr", lastN="stevens"},
                new stuffB{firstN="sss", lastN="jones"},
                new stuffB{firstN="ttt", lastN="smith"},
                new stuffB{firstN="uuu", lastN="Newman"},
                new stuffB{firstN="vvv", lastN="white"},
                new stuffB{firstN="www", lastN="stevens"},
                new stuffB{firstN="xxx", lastN="jones"},
                new stuffB{firstN="yyy", lastN="smith"},
                new stuffB{firstN="zzz", lastN="smith"}
            };
            return Detail.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public class stuffA
    {
        public string itm0 { get; set; }        
        public string itm1 { get; set; }
        public string itm2 { get; set; }
        public string itm3 { get; set; }
        public string itm4 { get; set; }
    }

    public class stuffB
    {
        public string firstN { get; set; }
        public string lastN { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found one workaround:

```
$(this).tooltip({ container: 'body', title: $(this).addClass("colr-tooltip"), title: titel, html: true, placement: "right" });
```

I added  -- container: 'body' -- to $(this).tooltip({.......}).  The one side effect though, is that I lose the css formatting of $(this).addClass("colr-tooltip"),   I will experiment with the placement of -- container: 'body' -- and see if that makes a difference.  Any other suggestions still appreciated - how I could keep the css formatting and keep the stabilization that -- container: 'body' -- appears to provide.  My searches suggest that Boostrap may be the culprit in the instability.

Answer (score 0):

turns out I can embed an html table with all the properties as follows -- kinda like inline css

```
var titel = typeof (data.d[n - 1]) === 'undefined' ? "" : "<table  style='color:blue;background-color:lightgreen;width:100px;text-align:left;'><tr><td>" + data.d[n - 1].firstN + "</td></tr><tr><td>" + data.d[n - 1].lastN + "</td></tr></table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

(for posterity) I found yet one more way to fix the tooltip jumping thing and still be able to use my original css class

```
/$(this).tooltip({ 'data-container': 'body', title: $(this).addClass("colr-tooltip"), title: titel, html: true, placement: "right" });
```

instead of container: 'body'  I replace that with 'data-container': 'body'

note that I have to wrap 'data-container' in single quotes for this version.

Comment: On repeated use with 'data-container': 'body'    the tooltip started jumping around again, so I'm scratching 'data-container': 'body'